# Angular e2e tests protractor chrome flags not working headless

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I am trying to set the cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure@2 in my protractor config, it works perfectly, when not running headless. But when I enable headless running it doesn't work and my test fail because of it. Is there a workaround or am i doing something wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

```
 capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'shardTestFiles': true,
    'maxInstances': 4,
    'chromeOptions': {
      args: [
        "lang=nl-NL",
        "--disable-gpu",
        "--window-size=1800,1080",
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disable-infobars",
        "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
        "--headless"
    ],
      prefs: {
        intl: { accept_languages: "nl-NL" },
      },
      localState: {
        'browser': {
          'enabled_labs_experiments': ['cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure@2']
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Luckily a PR was merged into selenium-nodejs that allows us to set the sameSite for addCookie (see: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/8652)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative I found that adding `--disable-features=CookiesWithoutSameSiteMustBeSecure,SameSiteByDefaultCookies` to the array of args to work. This is not really a fix for the fact that the flags are not working, but a workaround for this particular case.